Which is the correct regression model for predicting the association of climate with Julian days nested within decades?
Below is a reproducible example:
set.seed(123)

# Number of years
years <- 1961:2021

# Number of observations per year (e.g., 10)
obs_per_year <- 10

# Total number of observations
total_obs <- length(years) * obs_per_year

# Generate sample data
JulianDay <- sample(1:365, total_obs, replace = TRUE)
ClimaticVar1 <- rnorm(total_obs, mean = 10, sd = 2)
ClimaticVar2 <- rnorm(total_obs, mean = 5, sd = 1)

# Create Year and Decade factors
Year <- rep(years, each = obs_per_year)
Decade <- rep((years %/% 10) * 10, each = obs_per_year)

# Create data frame
df <- data.frame(
  JulianDay = JulianDay,
  ClimaticVar1 = ClimaticVar1,
  ClimaticVar2 = ClimaticVar2,
  Year = as.factor(Year),
  Decade = as.factor(Decade)
)

df

JulianDay ClimaticVar1 ClimaticVar2 Year Decade
1         179    10.038519     5.464091 1961   1960
2          14     7.845159     3.979599 1961   1960
3         195    11.425407     3.686549 1961   1960
4         306    12.169550     4.505519 1961   1960
5         118     5.550025     6.751757 1961   1960
6         299    12.471387     5.055765 1961   1960
7         229     7.517911     5.331434 1961   1960
8         244    10.909539     4.810153 1961   1960
9          14    11.319805     5.470493 1961   1960
10        153     9.600220     4.048320 1961   1960
11         90     8.709772     6.157910 1962   1960
12         91    10.330642     5.584705 1962   1960
13        256    10.877637     4.193547 1962   1960
14        197    11.766606     5.054553 1962   1960
15         91     5.895326     5.716332 1962   1960
16        348     6.727241     5.557731 1962   1960
17        137    12.860805     6.481934 1962   1960
18        355    12.093258     4.387012 1962   1960
19        328    10.870578     6.116137 1962   1960
20         26    11.430357     6.036548 1962   1960
21          7    11.834350     4.837517 1963   1960
22        137     4.678154     4.024073 1963   1960
23        254    12.220554     3.910855 1963   1960
24        211     9.030025     5.457787 1963   1960
25         78    10.461234     4.928873 1963   1960
26         81     9.409684     6.779103 1963   1960
27         43    11.743930     5.535138 1963   1960
28        359     9.303055     4.628055 1963   1960
29        332    11.037008     3.974458 1963   1960
30        143     9.218630     4.417598 1963   1960
31         32     7.814426     5.342888 1964   1960
32        109    12.420021     4.549065 1964   1960
33        263    11.481800     5.514230 1964   1960
34        330    13.448524     4.665662 1964   1960
35         23    10.130308     4.894440 1964   1960
36        309    12.250005     4.269490 1964   1960
37        135    13.950838     6.905044 1964   1960
38        309     9.437036     5.332622 1964   1960
39        224     7.354098     5.230634 1964   1960
40        166     9.521297     3.308138 1964   1960
41        217     9.571918     5.659792 1965   1960
42        290    10.303361     3.976376 1965   1960
43         69    13.424610     4.108478 1965   1960
44         72     9.347712     5.918341 1965   1960
45         76    10.746009     4.547299 1965   1960
46         63     9.544632     3.251628 1965   1960
47        141    10.040901     6.769904 1965   1960
48        210    10.628115     2.622593 1965   1960
49        353    12.656429     5.572812 1965   1960
50        347    10.242637     6.017249 1965   1960
51        153    11.425685     4.369032 1966   1960
52        294    11.557720     5.444287 1966   1960
53        277    11.829547     5.439130 1966   1960
54         41     8.851211     6.040623 1966   1960
55         90    13.253762     5.484099 1966   1960
56        316     9.238087     4.755116 1966   1960
57        223     9.788432     5.915992 1966   1960
58         16    12.808101     5.800622 1966   1960
59        116    12.588168     4.063431 1966   1960
60         94     7.820016     3.599213 1966   1960
61        262     8.253858     5.160278 1967   1960
62        235     7.283842     4.726038 1967   1960
63         86    10.363694     4.014461 1967   1960
64        342    10.329682     5.083931 1967   1960
65         39    10.728229     3.680003 1967   1960
66        159    11.104315     5.161226 1967   1960
67        240     8.796214     4.375072 1967   1960
68        209     8.012603     5.957164 1967   1960
69        306    12.053570     7.424489 1967   1960
70         34    11.502123     4.084021 1967   1960
71          4     6.981667     6.057664 1968   1960
72         13     9.809705     5.825150 1968   1960
73         69     8.208104     4.929806 1968   1960
74        243     5.858498     4.546354 1968   1960
75        308    10.300240     6.575308 1968   1960
76        278     9.841577     2.994542 1968   1960
77         89     9.805261     4.356805 1968   1960
78         25    10.432305     3.563157 1968   1960
79        291    11.764930     6.395313 1968   1960
80        286    10.411195     4.809297 1968   1960
81        159     8.767128     4.475329 1969   1960
82        121     8.530401     8.184044 1969   1960
83        110     9.736394     4.949963 1969   1960
84        158    10.620034     4.556251 1969   1960
85         64     7.920639     5.299865 1969   1960
86        199     9.631382     3.431575 1969   1960
87         67    11.934535     5.490303 1969   1960
88        151     9.783440     4.903837 1969   1960
89        335     8.603159     5.468525 1969   1960
90         85     9.448110     4.017629 1969   1960
91        165    12.229297     3.977016 1970   1970
92        136    11.100088     4.306585 1970   1970
93         51    12.473352     4.232010 1970   1970
94         74    10.278196     6.299050 1970   1970
95        178    10.820550     6.579146 1970   1970
96        362     8.883086     4.843108 1970   1970
97        236    11.210741     4.641063 1970   1970
98         98     8.987333     4.670961 1970   1970
99        330     7.158869     5.069236 1970   1970
100       214    10.255986     5.096904 1970   1970
101       127    13.891702     5.290034 1971   1970
102       212    11.601829     4.253321 1971   1970
103       174    12.330507     4.153104 1971   1970
104       273    10.717711     6.197078 1971   1970
105       302     8.782886     4.451373 1971   1970
106       310     9.595518     5.303046 1971   1970
107       232     9.453504     4.943029 1971   1970
108       243     9.062600     4.042151 1971   1970
109       350    11.408335     5.591062 1971   1970
110       335     7.605273     5.173105 1971   1970
111       280    11.732732     6.399783 1972   1970
112       113    11.728305     5.117460 1972   1970
113       107     7.602755     4.668454 1972   1970
114       151    11.278984     5.278295 1972   1970
115       154    14.860453     3.814408 1972   1970
116       102     8.885569     4.164106 1972   1970
117       255    11.689808     5.510273 1972   1970
118       160     8.435596     4.666879 1972   1970
119       155    12.221423     4.934039 1972   1970
120         5    10.499649     4.884778 1972   1970
121       326    13.303831     4.349487 1973   1970
122       272     7.082059     2.981311 1973   1970
123       280     9.897404     5.348835 1973   1970
124       288     8.946150     5.761640 1973   1970
125       277     9.605470     3.711284 1973   1970
126        55     8.740843     6.482403 1973   1970
127       331     8.332313     5.385155 1973   1970
128       238    11.157445     6.341640 1973   1970
129       252     7.824839     4.042830 1973   1970
130       339    12.968062     5.166781 1973   1970
131        39     7.627587     4.899986 1974   1970
132       310    10.202158     5.768507 1974   1970
133       137    11.065979     4.424140 1974   1970
134       226    11.173471     4.989902 1974   1970
135        48     9.396507     3.221341 1974   1970
136        77    10.159004     4.222379 1974   1970
137        83    11.922528     5.125034 1974   1970
138       184     7.087068     4.293679 1974   1970
139        39     8.436521     4.956431 1974   1970
140       196    10.640805     4.532074 1974   1970
141       257     9.110436     5.606930 1975   1970
142       168    12.740008     6.168488 1975   1970
143       286    11.346508     4.177499 1975   1970
144        94    10.144334     4.692963 1975   1970
145       272     6.984485     6.439761 1975   1970
146       344    10.052200     2.801077 1975   1970
147       310     9.367168     4.680162 1975   1970
148        20     9.795307     7.064704 1975   1970
149       360     7.636882     7.193590 1975   1970
150       195    10.997316     5.156595 1975   1970
151       349     7.922087     4.136391 1976   1970
152       164     9.547556     5.165457 1976   1970
153        52    10.762852     4.347226 1976   1970
154       364     8.432968     6.452817 1976   1970
155        22    11.165983     4.193517 1976   1970
156       177     7.366979     5.372912 1976   1970
157        42     4.380451     5.619850 1976   1970
158       315    10.929936     4.242490 1976   1970
159        84    11.681080     5.851525 1976   1970
160        11     9.428309     4.252070 1976   1970
161       121    11.008253     5.630240 1977   1970
162       302     7.688167     6.096662 1977   1970
163        85     9.745703     4.011557 1977   1970
164       365     6.116963     6.107995 1977   1970
165       194    12.362362     4.510467 1977   1970
166       107    13.719822     5.294353 1977   1970
167        77    12.148025     5.201837 1977   1970
168       198     9.945306     4.572804 1977   1970
169       249     9.933339     5.268103 1977   1970
170       200     6.967865     3.769569 1977   1970
171       160    11.580771     4.863863 1978   1970
172       250     9.578532     5.825791 1978   1970
173       292     8.686514     2.825875 1978   1970
174        16     7.175948     3.512074 1978   1970
175        33     9.400475     3.838062 1978   1970
176        40     8.301878     3.410910 1978   1970
177        10     9.205939     5.419583 1978   1970
178       200     7.564800     4.007072 1978   1970
179       125    13.375179     2.835453 1978   1970
180       265     9.967995     4.362431 1978   1970
181       263    12.149890     4.609365 1979   1970
182       186     4.796601     5.856785 1979   1970
183        61     9.093604     3.896248 1979   1970
184       252     8.649035     6.161289 1979   1970
185       152     7.554148     5.398363 1979   1970
186       319    13.093218     5.362352 1979   1970
187        54     7.169436     4.147474 1979   1970
188        26    10.636781     6.953668 1979   1970
189       235    11.692873     4.835729 1979   1970
190       289    10.356380     3.175102 1979   1970
191       185     8.249489     4.796144 1980   1980
192       253    11.882332     3.065556 1980   1980
193       115    10.341176     4.689490 1980   1980
194        10     7.873004     4.577773 1980   1980
195       309     7.223902     5.681830 1980   1980
196        54    14.173435     6.009496 1980   1980
197       205     8.642994     4.273895 1980   1980
198       363     6.288857     5.806109 1980   1980
199       267    11.066519     6.424323 1980   1980
200        25    10.620461     4.215856 1980   1980
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 410 rows ]


I would like to know which is the best regression model in which I can use Julian days as response variable, climate and decades as explanatory variables.
Thanks
Rahul
